# RGBD image to Pointcloud in ManipulationStation example

Tags: drake

In the current [commit](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/71f452c/examples/manipulation_station/manipulation_station.cc), ManipulationStation used DepthImageToPointCloud to project the point cloud from color image and depth image input. However, in the [documentation](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.perception.html?highlight=depthimagetopointcloud#pydrake.perception.DepthImageToPointCloud), it stated that

> Note that if a color image is provided, it must be in the same frame as the depth image.

In my understanding, both color and depth image input come from RgbdSensor which is created from the info from MakeD415CameraModel. Both C and D are two difference frames.

I think the resulting point cloud have a wrong coloring. I tested it on similar setup, but not the MakeD415CameraModel exactly. I currently solved this issue by forcing C and D to be the same frames in MakeD415CameraModel.

My question : Do drake have the method that map between depth image and color image from different frames, similar to [kinect library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/use-image-transformation)? Since this is the simulation after all, maybe this is overkill?

P.S. I am trying to simulate the image from Azure Kinect; hence the question.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, as of 10/29/2021 no such functionality has been implemented. You could put in a feature request in Drake (via a [new issue](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/new)).

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12125

Comment: I think there is a draft of solution in the issue mentioned. 
Thank you for both answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12125 discusses this problem, and has either a work-around (in case your simulation could fudge, and have the depth and camera frames identical even though that's slightly different than the real sensor) or a pointer to a different kind of solution (the cv2.registerDepth algorithm).  Eventually it would be nice to have registerDepth-like feature built in to drake, but as of today, it's not there yet.